# SQUID Proxy in a thinclient environment

Tags: proxy, http, squid, thin-client

I have an environment that uses thin client technology.  Many thin clients connect to a central server, log in, and get an X session under their username.  All requests to the internet come from the master server's IP.

I would like to set up a proxy to log traffic for diagnostic purposes, as users visiting cretin websites have been known to drive up the load on the server.  The flow will be as follows:

Thin Clients (1-n) ----> Server ----> SQUID ----> Internet

The issue is that this will not provide any useful logging information since every request simply comes from the central server.  Is there anyway I could possibly inject an "X-Forwarded-For: INSERT_USERNAME_HERE" into each HTTP request which squid will log and drop the header so that the website does not receive it.

Comment: is proxy with authentication an option?

Comment: No it needs to be transparent to the user.  If I could somehow force some pseudo authentication by hard setting the firefox proxy to user@proxy on login it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Squid supports [proxy authentication](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Authentication), forcing your users to log in to the proxy before they get access to the internet.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't want to have to set up all the user database and stuff.  That's why I'd rather somehow just stuff the username into a header.  Anyway I can set per-user proxy settings that are applied upon login?  I see that firefox has a "Use system proxy settings" bubble.  If I could set the "system proxy" setting for each user to username@proxy:port I could achieve the same effect.

Comment: you can try with http_proxy environment variable `http_proxy=http://username:password@hostname:port`